# C# - Object Declaration and Usage

Tags: c#, object

I've written this in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Object
{
    class Program
    {
        int hp;
        Program mob1 = new Program();
        Program player = new Program();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program go = new Program();
            go.next();
        }
        public void next()
        {
            mob1.hp = 50;
            player.hp = 100;
            Console.WriteLine("Player's HP: " + player.hp);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this program, I get a Stack Overflow exception, and the program just crashes.
The Exception happens at the declaration of the first object, mon.

Why is this? And how I can fix it?

Comment: Why are you creating multiple instances within the same program? Best describing what you are trying to do because you can be sure there is *definitely* a better way than what you are currently doing.

Comment: Every time you create a new instance of `Program`, it creates another new instance of `Program` itself, until you run out of memory.

Comment: Oh. Sorry I forgot to state, but I come from Java where such code is entirely possible, so it might have confused me. How can I declare these two objects, then, without creating infinite recursion?

Comment: @BarSharabani create *separate* class for those particular objects e.g. `public class Player { }` and create instances of that instead. I assume you understand [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) given you are coming from a Java background.

Comment: @BarSharabani I would love to see the java code that allows you to do this.

Comment: Even if Java _allows_, it does not mean you _have to_ write in such awful style

Comment: You've forgotten to accept the answer. Again.
[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

And you really should not rewrite you original question since it is Q&A site.

Comment: OK, accepted dcastro's answer.

And Mansfield, you asked for a Java code that does that without new classes. Here you go, I've updated the question with one that does it perfectly.

Comment: @BarSharabani: your java example works because Object is not instantiating another object as a field or in its constructor. You're instantiating new Objects as a result of a **single** call to static main - which is fine and won't generate infinite recursion. If you _do_ add a field like `private Object = new Object()`, it will crash. The two code snippets are not equivalent.

Comment: Oh, so it means that also in Java, if I want to make an object public between all methods (only voids), I have to declare it through a new class?

Comment: @BlueRay101 What do you mean by that?

Comment: @BlueRay101 You seem to have completely removed the original question from your question. Please keep the original question so future visitors know what you were asking about.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're generating infinite recursion.

Think about it this way:
When you start the application, you're creating an instance of the type `Program`. That instance, will create two other instances: `mob1` and `player`. Those two instances, will create two more each, and so on. Eventually, the program crashes.

You should create a specific class to hold a player's state and its `hp` - e.g., `public class Player{}`.

**Edit**

```
class Program
{
    Player mob1 = new Player(); // mob1 and player are now of type Player
    Player player = new Player();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Next();
    }

    static public void Next()
    {
        mob1.Hp = 50;
        player.Hp = 100;
        Console.WriteLine("Player's HP: " + player.Hp);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public int Hp {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: This _is_ the easiest way - and the appropriate one. This is exactly what classes in an object-oriented language are for.

Comment: Just a correction: it's not "a new class for each object". It's a new class for each domain model (not always true, but it illustrates the idea). In your application, you're dealing with a concept of a player - so you should create a class to model that.

Comment: Those are called "properties" in the c# world: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: @BarSharabani FYI you can create as many *instances* of `Program` you like, however, you just can't have internal fields being initialized using the same type - this is where the recursion happens.

Comment: May be he is trying to add a new property to the same class. `int hp;` `public int Hp {get {return hp;} set {hp = value;}}`

Comment: @BarSharabani At this point your questions are on completely different topics. Create a new question if you have further inquiries about OOP in C#.

Comment: Thats a simplified way of declaring private fields and public accessors. The compile will create a private backing field (`private int _hp`) and two public methods (`public int GetHp()` and `public void SetHp(int hp)`).

Answer (score 6):

It's crashing because you've just created an infinite loop - recursion, but without any means of ending. Every instance of your class creates new and new objects, eventually resulting in program crash.

Answer (score 1):

You have the Class Program with 2 fields of the Type Program 
which each of has 2 fields of the type Program

You created a infinite Loop of Variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your field declarations

```
Program mob1 = new Program();
```

etc. create an instance of `Program` every time an instance of `Program` is created...

This results in recurring creation of Program objects until there is no more memory on the stack.